# Default value for pixels_per_cell skimage.feature.hog

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scipy, computer-vision

I am working on some images where size of every image varies and wish to calculate the Histogram Oriented Gradient of each. I do not want to resize any of my image and yet want the HOG output to be of the same length for each. I know that the possible way to do so is to have a varying pixel per cell and fixed cell per block type. In doing so I was curious to find if no value is provided for the pixels_per_cell skimage.feature.hog will it be able to decide one for me or will I require my own logic to determine pixels_per_cell for every image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with specifying pixel per cell specific to the image keeping cell per block same for each.

```
 skimage.feature.hog(img, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(img.shape[0]/8,img.shape[1]/8),cells_per_block=(4, 4), block_norm='L2-Hys', visualize=False, visualise=None, transform_sqrt=False, feature_vector=True, multichannel=None)
```

Also [this link](https://www.researchgate.net/post/HOG_for_images_of_different_sizes2) provided fairly good enough solution to my problem.

Moreover the default pixels_per_cell (8x8) did not helped much as generated varying length HOGs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the HOG output of same length for different size images, then you should write the logic for the part where the image is divided into cells. For example, if your image size is `(224x224)` and you want `8` pixels per cells(the default value in skimage), then you will end up with `(28x28)` cells grid. Now suppose your next image is having dimensions `(448x448)`, then you should have pixels per cell that satisfies this equation `(224 /8) ==(448/x)`. You can easily solve for x from here. If you don't do this, then `skimage` will use the default value of `8` for pixels in each cell.

You can look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/feature/_hog.py#L47)

Comment: Since only you answered before I can figure things out myself so you deserve the bounty :)